# Set child div content according to grandparent div HTML CSS Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, responsive

I want to align the background image according to the grandparent element but it is aligning according to the parent element. Ive added **borders** for clarity.

Im considerring **photographyAndGraphicDesign** as the grandparent div

**row** as the parent div

**graphicDesign** and **Photography** as the child div

Please provide solution how can I fit the image according to the grandparent div and by using **% sign**

link
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-gould-g1yovc?file=/web1.css